# how to I replace a column value with the newest id after copying some columns to a new table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table like this

```
id parentid name
-- ------ ----
1    0      name1
2    1      name2
3    2      name3
4    0      name4
.    .       ....
```

After copying some rows to a new table I need to replace the parentid values to newly inserted ids if it is not 0 like below

```
ids parentids names
-- ------     ----
10     0      name1
11    10      name2
12    11      name3
13     0      name4
.  .          ....
```

How can I establish this using PHP and MySQL? Thank you.

Comment: Something like update mytable set parentids = ids where parentids != 0 ?

Comment: how do you know that 1,name1 has become 10,name1 on your new table? can you join both tables using just the name?

Comment: Are you using `0` in place of `NULL`?

Comment: I don't. It is just a primary ID created by mysql after I inserted the new row. It might be any other number

Comment: You should probably use `NULL`, meaning undefined, as `0` which is a reference to a non-existent row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably do whatever you can to keep the IDs the same. If this is unavoidable, you'll have to remap them:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _remap AS
  SELECT table_b.id AS new_id, table_a.id AS old_id
    FROM table_b
    LEFT JOIN table_a ON table_a.name=table_b.name

UPDATE table_b,_remap SET table_b.parent_id=_remap.new_id
  WHERE table_b.parent_id=_remap.old_id
```

This presumes your `name` column is unique.

Comment: Tadman, it gave me more headaches then I had before. So, I found a different way to do this. I created a old_table column on the new table and copied the old table's id' s in there. Now, I do my calculation using this new row instead of ids column. Thank you to everyone.

Comment: That's another way to do it. You can drop the additional column after the remapping.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'to a newly inserted ids', but this may help you get started:

```
UPDATE tableName SET `parentid` = '(Enter new value here)' WHERE parentid != 0;
```

Comment: In table 1, id 2 has a parentid of 1. When I copy this row to a new table(table 2), a new id is created. I just need to replace the table 1's parentid which is 1 to a new id which is 10 or any other number. I hope this makes sense.